# How can I find out which cache is still active?

Tags: caching

I have been walking through this page https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914 but I still have to hit clear cache during development process.

```
vendor/bin/drupal site:mode dev
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
 Configuration name: system.performance
 ------------------------- ---------------- ---------------- 
  Configuration key         Original Value   Override Value  
 ------------------------- ---------------- ---------------- 
  cache.page.use_internal                    false           
  css.preprocess            false            false           
  css.gzip                  true             false           
  js.preprocess             false            false           
  js.gzip                   true             false           
  response.gzip                              false           
 ------------------------- ---------------- ---------------- 

 Configuration name: views.settings
 -------------------------------- ---------------- ---------------- 
  Configuration key                Original Value   Override Value  
 -------------------------------- ---------------- ---------------- 
  ui.show.sql_query.enabled        false            true            
  ui.show.performance_statistics   false            true            
 -------------------------------- ---------------- ---------------- 

 Configuration name: system.logging
 ------------------- ---------------- ---------------- 
  Configuration key   Original Value   Override Value  
 ------------------- ---------------- ---------------- 
  error_level         hide             all             
 ------------------- ---------------- ---------------- 


 Services files "/var/www/web/sites/default/services.yml" was overwritten                               


 New services settings
 ------------------------------------------ ------------- ------- 
  Service                                    Parameter     Value  
 ------------------------------------------ ------------- ------- 
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers                 true   
  twig.config                                auto_reload   true   
  twig.config                                cache         true   
  twig.config                                debug         true   
 ------------------------------------------ ------------- ------- 


 // cache:rebuild

 Rebuilding cache(s), wait a moment please.

 [OK] Done clearing cache(s).
```

Aggregation of js and css are off too.

How can I find out which of the cache systems still runs?

Comment: This only disables caches most relevant to theming. If you develop other things it might not help much or can be counterproductive, see https://www.dx-experts.nl/blog/2017/drupal-8-development-caching

Comment: When doing what? Give an example...

Comment: Yes I mean when I am theming

Comment: I have now tried everything. When I edit the style.css nothing happens untill I delete all caches manually... how can I find out which caches are running? I wanted to disable ALL cachings COMPLETELY

Comment: CSS files are delivered directly through the webserver to the browser. Either adjust the response headers of CSS files in the webserver or switch to dev mode in your browser, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development.

Comment: I had made sure, that I have disabled browser cache when DevTools are open. Actually I always have that option on. However back to the original question: How can I list all caches and their backends that are currently active?